# How can I display an nested object attribute on last in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have a two models: Client has_many Status in a nested relationship.

In my client index I am showing a table of all client attrs.  I want to show the most recent status.

I have tried two things:

**First:** `<%= client.statuses.last.name %>` 
"last" in this case is not an attribute but a "last" method from the [ruby api](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/last)

**And second:** 
I created a Client model method

```
def latest_status
  current = self.statuses.last
  return current
end
```

and then in the view:

```
<%= client.latest_status.name %>
```

Both return:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

The caveat is that if I run debug(client.statuses.last) in the view, it prints out the attrs from the correct status.

-- EDIT 
User has_many :statuses
Status belongs_to :user

Those are the model associations.

running debug(client.statuses.last) it returns:

```
--- !ruby/object:Status
attributes:
 id: 6
 name: Prospect
 value: 40000
 created_at: 2014-06-20 20:03:14.904934000 Z
 updated_at: 2014-06-20 20:03:14.904934000 Z
 client_id: 1
```

but I can't access the 'name' attribute with 'last'.

-- Edit 6/20
I continue to try and get this done, and I was able to achieve part of the solution but I dont think its very scaleable.

```
 <% client.statuses.each_with_index do |s, i| %>
        <% if i == 0 %>
          <%= s.name %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

By doing a simple .each_with_index loop I can get access to the first item or the last object.  But if there was a lot of nested items.  I feel like that would be a super big query.  I only need the most recent in this case.

Comment: What's your `Client` and `Status` models?

Comment: Yes, this is not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Added model relationships. my apologies.

Comment: We need a bit more information. What do you mean by "But if I simply debug (`client.statuses.last`) it returns the right result"? Can you show the entire view containing the line in code in question, and the entire controller method for that view?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c964073430b47c96658

Comment: have you verified, that all clients really have at least one status? If there is one client within your collection having no status, you will see the error message you mentioned. try changing the command to `client.statuses.last.name if client.statuses.any?` or in short: `client.statuses.last.try :name`

Comment: Peter that was it.  Many thanks.  Submit that as an answer and I'll approve.

Answer (score 1):

Your view code does not check if a client has any status, so if at least one client in your collection has no status, calling `last` on it will return `nil` and thus throw the error you see.

Solve it by either explicitly check for statuses:

```
client.statuses.last.name if client.statuses.any?
```

or in short with

```
client.statuses.last.try :name
```